# iOS - Send email with ActiveSync account

Tags: ios, exchange-server, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I have add a feature to send email in my application, with `MFMailComposeViewController`. This feature work well when a GMail,Hotmail or Yahoo account is registered on my iPad, but it does not work when I have an Microsoft Exchange account registered !

In fact, the call of the method `[MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]` returns `FALSE` for an Microsoft Exchange account. I tried my application on several devices with different accounts, it seems to be a bug between `MFMailComposeViewController` and Microsoft Exchange.

Are there another way to send an email without `MFMailComposeViewController`? What are your suggestions?

Comment: There is no ActiveSync available for iOS, did you mean Exchange?

Comment: Yes I did, an Exchange ActiveSync account

Comment: Ok so a Microsoft Exchange account (there is no Active Sync).

Comment: Correct. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Not really, you can't send mail other then with the `MFMailComposeViewController`. You might be able to open the mail app with the `mail://` app scheme. But other then that you are out of luck.

Comment: And do you know something about this bug with Exchange? I do not understand why [MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail] return NO when I can use my Exchange account normally in Mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I fix my problem with my Exchange account.

I use MobileIron to configure my device and it was the certificate properties that didn't allow me to send email from another application that Mail!

So now, it works and I have not search another way to send e-mail than MFMailComposeViewController.